# SAP PI web service which calls multiple RFCs

Tags: web-services, saprfc, sap-pi, sap-xi

I have asked an SAP PI vendor developer to create a single web service with multiple operations ,where each operation would call an RFC , I am being told it will need to be a single RFC and single operation , is it not possible to have single web service with multiple operations where each operation calls an RFC ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a PI or RFC expert, but I believe this is correct.  Multiple RFC calls will not be made in the same session.  You should build a custom RFC that calls each of the functions you need in turn, so that PI can make a single call.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is yes you can. You can develop as many operations as you want for a web service and each calling a separate RFC. For example I have a WebSalesOrder WebService with Create, Change, Confirm operations and of course, each works differently. If you are trying to develop an operation that calls multiple RFCs that is also possible but more complex to develop, you can query Integration processes in PI and you will see one way this is accomplished. Not knowing specifically what you are trying to accomplish I would make sure the requirement is understood and maybe there is something more specific that causes your specific requirement to not be possible.

Later........

Comment: Thanks , yes the req is to call a seperate rfc from each webservice operation, can you please mention high level steps?

Comment: The process is the same either the difference lies in the setup of the service interface, 

1. Setup the message or data types, 
2. Define your mappings,
3. Define the service interface (the service interface is where you combine all the operations into one service, ie. create, change, delete etc.
a. For each operation, you specify which specific message type, error message Is sent or received

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. As of SAP PI 7.1 it is possible to create a service interface with multiple operations and each of these operations can be calling a different RFC in the back-end SAP system.